# unresolved external symbol _IID_IDXGIAdapter4

Tags: visual-c++, directx

It is really weird....

I think this symbol `_IID_IDXGIAdapter4` in `dxguid.lib`, but when I use `DUMPBIN` command to check the symbols inside the dll. There are `_IID_IDXGIAdapter1~3`, no `_IID_IDXGIAdapter4`.

Windows SDK : `10.0.18362.0`

And most weird is I found a DX12 tutorial that using IDXGIAdapter4 and I can compile it successfully, but my project can't, even I copy his project setting.

https://github.com/jpvanoosten/LearningDirectX12/blob/v0.0.1/Tutorial1/src/main.cpp

In this project, he only use `d3d12.lib` ,`dxgi.lib` ,`dxguid.lib`, and I already put them into project setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an oversight and is fixed in the next Windows 10 SDK after the current one (i.e. 19041 still has the bug).

DXGUID.LIB was missing:

- `IID_IDXGIAdapter4`
- `IID_IDXGIOutput6`
- `IID_IDXGIFactory6`
- `IID_IDXGIFactory7`

> It was reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/issues/622) as well.

There's nothing special about `dxguid.lib`. It's just code like this:

```
#define INITGUID
#include <Windows.h>

#include <d3dcommon.h>

#include <dxgi1_5.h>
#include <dxgidebug.h>

#include <d3d11_4.h>
#include <d3d11shader.h>
#include <d3d11sdklayers.h>

#include <d3dcompiler.h>

#include <d3d12.h>
#include <d3d12video.h>
#include <d3d12shader.h>
#include <d3d12sdklayers.h>
```

> The bug was using `dxgi1_5.h` in the dxguid library source, but I updated it to use `dxgi1_6.h`.

Note that most of the "COM" GUIDs such as for Windows Imaging Component (WIC) are in `uuid.lib`.

**UPDATE**: This bug in `dxguid.lib` is fixed in  [Windows 10 SDK (20348), version 2104](https://aka.ms/windowssdk).

Comment: Well, that's why it was missed... ``__uidof`` doesn't need the C linkage as it's "magic compiler metadata". Our internal tests use ``__uuidof`` and therefore missed the fact that it was missing from ``dxguid.lib``. Keep in mind that ``dxguid.lib`` is a convenience helper utility, you can create the declaration yourself if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
pDxgiAdapter1->QueryInterface(IID_IDXGIAdapter4, (LPVOID *)p_ppDxgiAdapter4);
```

change to

```
pDxgiAdapter1->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter4), (LPVOID *)p_ppDxgiAdapter4);
```

solve my problem

but in `dxgi1_6.h`

```
DEFINE_GUID(IID_IDXGIAdapter4,0x3c8d99d1,0x4fbf,0x4181,0xa8,0x2c,0xaf,0x66,0xbf,0x7b,0xd2,0x4e);
```

I still can't use `IID_IDXGIAdapter4`.